# How to insert values ​into a column from another table?

Tags: pandas

I have two datasets:

First dataset:

```
Name     ID
Alla     3
Peter    NaN
Sara     NaN
Maria    NaN
```

Second dataset:

```
Name_name   ID_ID
Alla        3
Peter       4
Sara        5
```

I need to insert into the missing values ​​of the first table, the ID of the second table according to a common attribute in pandas. How to do it. I'm completely confused.

The result:
First dataset

```
Name     ID
Alla     3
Peter    4
Sara     5
Maria    NaN
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`Series.map`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) with [`Series.fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.fillna.html) for replace by `Series` with `index` by `Name_name` column created by [`DataFrame.set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) and selected `ID_ID`:

```
s = df2.set_index('Name_name')['ID_ID']
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].fillna(df1['Name'].map(s))
print (df1)
    Name   ID
0   Alla  3.0
1  Peter  4.0
2   Sara  5.0
```

If possible no missing values:

```
s = df2.set_index('Name_name')['ID_ID']
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].fillna(df1['Name'].map(s)).astype(int)
```

else:

```
s = df2.set_index('Name_name')['ID_ID']
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].fillna(df1['Name'].map(s)).astype('Int64')
```

EDIT: If got error :

> Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects

it means there are duplicates in `Name_name` column like `Alla` is duplicated, so `map` not know which value is used and error is rased.

```
print (df2)
  Name_name  ID_ID
0      Alla      3
1     Peter      4
2      Sara      5
3      Alla      8
```

Possible solution is remove duplicates with keep first dupes rows by [`DataFrame.drop_duplicates`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.drop_duplicates.html):

```
s = df2.drop_duplicates('Name_name').set_index('Name_name')['ID_ID']
df1['ID'] = df1['ID'].fillna(df1['Name'].map(s))
print (df1)
    Name   ID
0   Alla  3.0
1  Peter  4.0
2   Sara  5.0
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! But I have the mistake 'Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects'. What if I have some names missed in Second dataset. Can we correct this

Comment: @MarySmith - Me too, answer was edited with sample data for error and solution, btw your edited sample data working nice with original solution.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I see now)